# Parts of Speech Tagging NLTK SVM

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, nltk, svm

I am trying to write one Parts of Speech(PoS) Tagger in NLTK with Support Vector Machine (SVM). I could write upto a classifier as given in

```
>>> #CLASSIFICATION USING SUPPORT VECTOR MACHINE
>>> import nltk
>>> from nltk.classify import SklearnClassifier
>>> from sklearn.naive_bayes import BernoulliNB
>>> from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
>>> from sklearn.svm import SVC
>>> #TRAINING AND TEST DATA
>>> train = [('I love this sandwich.', 'pos'),
('This is an amazing place!', 'pos'),
('I feel very good about these beers.', 'pos'),
('This is my best work.', 'pos'),
("What an awesome view", 'pos'),
('I do not like this restaurant', 'neg'),
('I am tired of this stuff.', 'neg'),
("I can't deal with this", 'neg'),
('He is my sworn enemy!', 'neg'),
('My boss is horrible.', 'neg')]
>>> test = [
        ('The beer was good.', 'pos'),
        ('I do not enjoy my job', 'neg'),
        ("I ain't feeling dandy today.", 'neg'),
        ("I feel amazing!", 'pos'),
        ('Gary is a friend of mine.', 'pos'),
        ("I can't believe I'm doing this.", 'neg')]
>>> test_sentence = "This is the best band I've ever heard!"
>>> #FEATURESETS
>>> all_words = set(word.lower() for passage in train for word in word_tokenize(passage[0]))
>>> t = [({word: (word in word_tokenize(x[0])) for word in all_words}, x[1]) for x in train]
>>> testf=[({word: (word in word_tokenize(x[0])) for word in all_words}, x[1]) for x in test]
>>> test_sent_features = {word.lower(): (word in word_tokenize(test_sentence.lower())) for word in all_words}
>>> #CLASSIFICATION
>>> #SUPPORT VECTOR MACHINE
>>> classif1 = SklearnClassifier(SVC(), sparse=False).train(t)
>>> classif1.classify(test_sent_features)
'neg'
```

I have tried to use

```
from nltk.tag.sequential import ClassifierBasedPOSTagger
```

and also,

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
```

but without much help. 
It seems NLTK also has one SVM classifier as given in,

```
from nltk.classify import svm
```

but somehow failing to connect.

I tried them as follows and received the corresponding error reports.

```
>>> import nltk
>>> from nltk.classify import SklearnClassifier
>>> from sklearn.naive_bayes import BernoulliNB
>>> from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
>>> from sklearn.svm import SVC
>>> from nltk.corpus import brown
>>> brown_trd=brown.tagged_sents()[:300]
>>> from nltk.tag.sequential import ClassifierBasedPOSTagger
>>> clf = SklearnClassifier(SVC(),sparse=False)
>>> svm_tagger = ClassifierBasedPOSTagger(train=brown_trd,
classifier_builder=clf.train)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#9>", line 2, in <module>
    classifier_builder=clf.train)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\tag\sequential.py", line 630, in __init__
    self._train(train, classifier_builder, verbose)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\tag\sequential.py", line 667, in _train
    self._classifier = classifier_builder(classifier_corpus)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\classify\scikitlearn.py", line 115, in train
    X = self._vectorizer.fit_transform(X)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\dict_vectorizer.py", line 226, in fit_transform
    return self._transform(X, fitting=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\dict_vectorizer.py", line 174, in _transform
    values.append(dtype(v))
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number

>>> from nltk.classify import svm
>>> svm_tagger = ClassifierBasedPOSTagger(train=brown_trd,
classifier_builder=svm.train)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#11>", line 2, in <module>
    classifier_builder=svm.train)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'train'

>>> from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer
>>> from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
>>> train_data=TfidfTransformer(brown_trd)
>>> train_data1=DictVectorizer(brown_trd)
>>> svm_tagger = ClassifierBasedPOSTagger(train=train_data,
classifier_builder=svm.train)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#16>", line 2, in <module>
    classifier_builder=svm.train)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'train'

>>> svm_tagger = ClassifierBasedPOSTagger(train=train_data1,
classifier_builder=svm.train)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#17>", line 2, in <module>
    classifier_builder=svm.train)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'train'
>>> svm_tagger = ClassifierBasedPOSTagger(train=train_data,
classifier_builder=clf.train)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#18>", line 2, in <module>
    classifier_builder=clf.train)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\tag\sequential.py", line 630, in __init__
    self._train(train, classifier_builder, verbose)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\tag\sequential.py", line 656, in _train
    for sentence in tagged_corpus:
TypeError: 'TfidfTransformer' object is not iterable
>>> svm_tagger = ClassifierBasedPOSTagger(train=train_data1,
classifier_builder=clf.train)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#19>", line 2, in <module>
    classifier_builder=clf.train)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\tag\sequential.py", line 630, in __init__
    self._train(train, classifier_builder, verbose)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\tag\sequential.py", line 656, in _train
    for sentence in tagged_corpus:
TypeError: 'DictVectorizer' object is not iterable
>>> svm_tagger=ClassifierBasedPOSTagger(train=train_data,classifier_builder
= lambda train_feats: clf.train(train_data))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#20>", line 2, in <module>
    = lambda train_feats: clf.train(train_data))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\tag\sequential.py", line 630, in __init__
    self._train(train, classifier_builder, verbose)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\tag\sequential.py", line 656, in _train
    for sentence in tagged_corpus:
TypeError: 'TfidfTransformer' object is not iterable
>>> vm_tagger=ClassifierBasedPOSTagger(train=train_data1,classifier_builder
= lambda train_feats: clf.train(train_data1))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#21>", line 2, in <module>
    = lambda train_feats: clf.train(train_data1))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\tag\sequential.py", line 630, in __init__
    self._train(train, classifier_builder, verbose)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\tag\sequential.py", line 656, in _train
    for sentence in tagged_corpus:
TypeError: 'DictVectorizer' object is not iterable
>>> from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
>>> count_vect = CountVectorizer()
>>> X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(brown_trd)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#24>", line 1, in <module>
    X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(brown_trd)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line 817, in fit_transform
    self.fixed_vocabulary_)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line 752, in _count_vocab
    for feature in analyze(doc):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line 238, in <lambda>
    tokenize(preprocess(self.decode(doc))), stop_words)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line 204, in <lambda>
    return lambda x: strip_accents(x.lower())
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'
>>> X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(train_data)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#25>", line 1, in <module>
    X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(train_data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line 817, in fit_transform
    self.fixed_vocabulary_)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line 751, in _count_vocab
    for doc in raw_documents:
TypeError: 'TfidfTransformer' object is not iterable
>>> X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(train_data1)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#26>", line 1, in <module>
    X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(train_data1)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line 817, in fit_transform
    self.fixed_vocabulary_)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line 751, in _count_vocab
    for doc in raw_documents:
TypeError: 'DictVectorizer' object is not iterable
>>> X_new_counts = count_vect.transform(brown_trd)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#27>", line 1, in <module>
    X_new_counts = count_vect.transform(brown_trd)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line 863, in transform
    self._check_vocabulary()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line 275, in _check_vocabulary
    check_is_fitted(self, 'vocabulary_', msg=msg),
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 678, in check_is_fitted
    raise NotFittedError(msg % {'name': type(estimator).__name__})
NotFittedError: CountVectorizer - Vocabulary wasn't fitted.
>>> X_new_counts = count_vect.transform(train_data)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#28>", line 1, in <module>
    X_new_counts = count_vect.transform(train_data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line 863, in transform
    self._check_vocabulary()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line 275, in _check_vocabulary
    check_is_fitted(self, 'vocabulary_', msg=msg),
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 678, in check_is_fitted
    raise NotFittedError(msg % {'name': type(estimator).__name__})
NotFittedError: CountVectorizer - Vocabulary wasn't fitted.
>>> X_new_counts = count_vect.transform(train_data1)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#29>", line 1, in <module>
    X_new_counts = count_vect.transform(train_data1)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line 863, in transform
    self._check_vocabulary()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line 275, in _check_vocabulary
    check_is_fitted(self, 'vocabulary_', msg=msg),
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 678, in check_is_fitted
    raise NotFittedError(msg % {'name': type(estimator).__name__})
NotFittedError: CountVectorizer - Vocabulary wasn't fitted.
>>>
```

I feel I need to convert *brown.tagged_sents()* into sklearn format which I am failing and NLTK SVM is not fully developed.

If anyone may kindly suggest how to fix this issue.

Comment: When you say fail to connect, what error are you getting?

Comment: See http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. As there are multiple errors on various tries they may not fit here and may be unreadable as much indentation/formatting is not allowed here. I am revising the question with error reports.